# Unable to redefine litres unit in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I'm using `siunitx` to format units correctly. One of the units I need to use is litres - but the default `l` looks too much like a numerical `1` for me. I'd like to use a lower-case curly l (`\ell` will serve the purpose well).

The problem is, I don't seem to be able to redefine the existing unit macro. Creating a *new* macro does work though.

Code below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\l}{\ell}
\DeclareSIUnit{\myl}{\ell}

\begin{document}
\si{\l} \si{\myl} $\ell$
\end{document}
```

[image: Output: \l does not get redefined correctly]

Comment: @mico This doesn't explain why the \si{\l} doesn't work as expected though. I'm still curious ;-)

Comment: If you read section 5.11 of the `siunitx` manual, `\l` is an abbreviated unit (full list in table 21).

Also, it might be worth (me) noting that by default, `\litre` will output `l`, and `\liter` will output `L`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is (possibly) really silly - but the comments above gave me the clue. The `\l` macro is an *abbreviation* of the `\litre` macro. Redefining `\litre` also redefines `\l`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\litre}{\ell}

\begin{document}
\si{\l} $\ell$
\end{document}
```

[image: \litre redefines \l]

Comment: Section 5.11 of the siunitx manual.

`As standard, siunitx loads a set of abbreviated versions of the SI units (Table 21).`